# Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol web::websockets::client::websocket_callback_client

Tags: c++, vcpkg, cpprest-sdk

I'm attempting to use cpprestsdk, to establish a simple websocket connection:

```
#include <cpprest/ws_client.h>
using namespace web;
using namespace web::websockets::client;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    websocket_callback_client client;
    client.connect(U("ws://localhost:1234")).then([]() { /* We've finished connecting. */ });
}
```

However, when I run the application I get `error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall web::websockets::client::websocket_callback_client::websocket_callback_client(void)" (??0websocket_callback_client@client@websockets@web@@QAE@XZ)`

I have included `bcrypt.lib;winhttp.lib;crypt32.lib;` in Linker, and also made reference to `_NO_ASYNCRTIMP;` in C/C++ -> Preprocessor, but I can't seem to escape this issue.

I can make simple http requests with the SDK it appears only websockets are causing the issue. I also installed this package using VCPKG and am using the Win32 build of the sdk.

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 2):

You need to install websockets feature:

```
.\vcpkg install cpprestsdk[websockets] --recurse
```

Comment: Tank you! After hours of searching this solved my issue, could you please explain how this is different from a normal `vcpkg install cpprestsdk` command?